# How price in Uniswap and PancakeSwap is formed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, decentralized-applications

I am creating an exchange similar to pancakeswap with limited features like exchange and liquidity only.

I am using the Pancake router contract code https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xd99d1c33f9fc3444f8101754abc46c52416550d1.

We are giving the price at the time of creating pair for our token with BNB by adding liquidity by calling **addLiquidityETH** function in router contract. Its working and creating pair. Then the value is fixed for that pair.

Having some doubts.

1. What is that value?
2. If the price of the BNB Increases in market. How can we fetch the current market price and update in our own DEX?
3. Is this contract will do this or we have to call any other API providing API....

I gonethrough the https://uniswap.org/docs/v2. But I didnt find the solution for above queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then the value is fixed for that pair

You cannot fix value at open markets.

> What is that value?

[You can find out about price formation in Uniswap v2 and other bonding curve exchange here](https://docs.ethhub.io/guides/graphical-guide-for-understanding-uniswap/). Essentially, value is set by buyers and sellers, depending on how much they buy or sell.

> If the price of the BNB Increases in market. How can we fetch the current market price and update in our own DEX?

You cannot, because the value is set by buyers and sellers. You need become buyer and seller and spend money to set the price, effectively *market make* your token pair.

> Is this contract will do this or we have to call any other API providing API

Does not make to discuss this, as your earlier assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. I am using getAmountsOut method to find ratio before adding liquidity. Is this correct? If wrong pl.suggest the correct method..